# I can't connect to my wifi anymore

Tags: wireless

Yesterday and today morning it worked, but suddenly it does not anymore.

My wifi is working 100% since I can connect my phone to it and other computers.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/26365066/

I tried the Random Mac fix in NetworkManager.conf and restarted but no success.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64-bit with Gnome Desktop

Comment: Have you checked all the "obvious" things like IP conflict? (i.e. the router giving another device the IP the computer is trying to use)

Comment: Solved my restarting *hides in shame*

Answer (score 0):

Wifi had always worked for me on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop.  Suddenly, yesterday, it stopped working. (But weirdly, I *could* connect to the "guest" network of my wifi router, just not the main network.)

Restarting my laptop didn't solve the wifi problem for me.

What worked for me was to **restart the ARRIS BGW210-700 wifi gateway** that AT&T fiber requires me to use.